# How can I unpin a thread after pinning to a core using sched_setaffinity?

Tags: linux, multithreading, process

I am currently using [`sched_setaffinity`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity) to pin a thread to a particular CPU core.

```
void setCpuAffinity(int id) {                                            
    cpu_set_t cpuset;                                                    

    CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);                                                   
        CPU_SET(id, &cpuset);                                            
        assert(sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpuset), &cpuset) == 0);      
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find a corresponding function to **unpin** the thread from any given core, and allow the kernel to schedule the thread on any core.

**How can I reverse the effect of CPU pinning and allow free movement of a thread once again?**

I am aware that one hack would be to use `CPU_OR` and add every CPU ID to the allowable set, but I am looking for a less hacky approach that restores the state of a thread to the state before `sched_setaffinity` was ever called.

Comment: `sched_setaffinity` appears to be setting a mask, not choosing a CPU.  Set the most permissive mask?

Comment: @phs, That would be the hack I described at the bottom of the question. There doesn't seem to be a clean way to say "most permissive mask".

Comment: Ah, so it is.  Why not just get the existing mask before calling `sched_setaffinity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @phs's suggestion, I wrote the following two functions, which are called before and after cpu pinning to unpin the thread. This successfully unpins the CPU.

```
void setCpuAffinity(cpu_set_t cpuset) {                                
    assert(sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpuset), &cpuset) == 0);        
}                                                                      

cpu_set_t getCpuAffinity() {                                             
    cpu_set_t cpuset;                                                    

    CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);                                                   
    assert(sched_getaffinity(0, sizeof(cpuset), &cpuset) == 0);          
    return cpuset;                                                       
}
```